# How do i make a familiar looking status bar on a view controller when i present a particular view controller modally?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, statusbar

When a UIViewController is pushed over a UINavigationController it has a consistent looking native status bar. But when a UIViewController is pushed **'modally'** it does not contain a navigation bar. After adding a navigation bar manually the status bar of that UIViewController still remains white. How do i make it consistent to the previous UIViewController's status bar (i.e. grey in colour)
Here's an image to demonstrate the issue visually.

[image]

Comment: in here u need to embed with navigation controller in before VC

Comment: First VC is on NC, the stack can stay on that one NC right? Why will I need a NC before every VC?

Answer (score 0):

**step-1**

on your second VC , you need to embed with Navigation Controller, for e.g

[image]

**step-2**

on your second VC, add bar button for dismiss the present VC,

```
 @IBAction func btnback(_ sender: Any) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```